# Avoiding html thinking you are using a custom tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to output a text value from a php array. The value is

```
<Carlos>
```

However when echo'd to the page nothing shows because the browser has transformed it to

`<Carlos></Carlos>`

How do I stop it from transforming it into tags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Escape it, for example using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities). You'd end up with:

```
&lt;Carlos&gt;
```

Comment: (`htmlspecialchars` is normally to be preferred. `htmlentities` will usually-needlessly encode all non-ASCII characters, and if you don't tell it your encoding it will mess them up badly. `htmlspecialchars` only entity-references the few characters that really need it.)

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to print

```
&lt;Carlos&gt;
```

? Apply [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the string to echo.

Answer (score 1):

if all you've written on the page is `<Carlos>` HTML won't automatically parse it to `<Carlos></Carlos>`. I reckon its the view source of your browser.

try

`&lt;Carlos&gt;`